# Deshabilitar opciones de un select dependiendo de otro select

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo la duda de como poder deshabilitar opciones de un **`select`**, dependiendo de otro **`select`**.

Por ejemplo:

```
//SELECT 1
<select class="opciones">
    <option value="1">Opcion 1</option>
    <option value="2">Opcion 2</option>
</select>

//SELECT 2
<select>
    <option value="1">Ejemplo #1</option>
    <option value="2">Ejemplo #2</option>
    <option value="3">Ejemplo #3</option>
    <option value="4">Ejemplo #4</option>
</select>
```

Al momento de elegir, por ejemplo, en el **`select1`**  elegir **`opcion 1`**, entonces deshabilitar en el segundo **`select2`**: **`ejemplo 1`** y **`ejemplo 2`**.

```
$(".caja").on("change",".opciones",function(){
    /*obtener opciones elegidas del select*/
    var opciones = $(".opciones option:selected");

    opciones = parseInt(opciones);

    if(opciones == 1)
    {
        // ??
    }

});
```

¿De qué forma se podría realizar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo puedes lograr de este modo con JS puro:

- Empiezo por agregarle un `id` único a cada `select`
- Obtén el texto que esta entre las etiquetas de apertura y cierre de `<option></option>` con ayuda de la propiedad `text`
- Nos apoyamos del evento `change` para *escuchar* cuando ocurre una selección en el menú desplegable
- Guradamos en una variable la selección que hizo el usuario y con un condicional simple verificamos si el texto almacenado coincide con **Opcion 1**
- El segundo `select` que tenemos es una lista de nodos por lo cual lo podemos tratar como un vector
- Entonces para deshabilitar las 2 opciones deseadas basta con indicar entre corchetes la posición numérica que ocupan
- Accedemos a la propiedad  `disabled` la cual le asignamos un valor *booleano* como `true`

**EJEMPLO**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Ejemplo</title>
</head>
<body>
<select id="opciones1">
    <option value="0">Opcion 0</option>
    <option value="1">Opcion 1</option>
    <option value="2">Opcion 2</option>
</select>

//SELECT 2
<select id="opciones2">
    <option value="1">Ejemplo #1</option>
    <option value="2">Ejemplo #2</option>
    <option value="3">Ejemplo #3</option>
    <option value="4">Ejemplo #4</option>
</select>
<script>
    let opciones1 = document.getElementById("opciones1")
    let opciones2 = document.getElementById("opciones2")
    
    opciones1.addEventListener("change", () => {
      let texto = opciones1.options[opciones1.selectedIndex].text
      if (texto === "Opcion 1") {
       opciones2[0].disabled = true
       opciones2[1].disabled = true
      } 
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Una vez que estén deshabilitados, si elegimos cualquier otra opción del menú los podemos volver a habilitar manejando ese comportamiento en la estructura del condicional por medio del bloque *else* así:

```
else {
       opciones2[0].disabled = false
       opciones2[1].disabled = false
      }
```

**Edición**

La misma solución pero con un enfoque **orientado a objetos**:

```
class Desplegable {
  constructor(menuUno, menuDos) {
    this.menuUno = menuUno
    this.menuDos = menuDos
  }

  deshabilitaElementos() {
    this.menuUno.addEventListener("change", () => {
     (this.menuUno.options[this.menuUno.selectedIndex].text === "Opcion 1") 
      ? (this.menuDos[0].disabled = true, this.menuDos[1].disabled = true) 
      : (this.menuDos[0].disabled = false, this.menuDos[1].disabled = false)
    })
  }
}

let menuUno1 = document.getElementById("opciones1")
let menuDos2 = document.getElementById("opciones2")
const cambio = new Desplegable(menuUno1, menuDos2)
cambio.deshabilitaElementos()
```